# How do I convert a string to a number in R if the string contains a letter?

Tags: r

I am currently helping a friend with his research and am gathering information about different natural disasters that occured from 2004-2016. The data can be found using this link:
https://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/swdi/stormevents/csvfiles/
when you import it to R it gives helpful information, however, my friend, and now I, am only interested in State, Year, Month, Event, Type, County, Direct & indirect deaths and injuries, and property damage. So first I am extracting the columns I need and will later in the code combine them back together, however the data is currently in string mode, for the Property Damage column I need it to present as numeric since it is in cash value. So for example, I have a data entry in that column that looks like "8.6k" and I need it as this 8600 and for all the "NA" entries to be replaced with a 0.

I have this so far but it gives me back a string of "NA"s. Can anyone think of a better way of doing this?

```
State<- W2004$STATE
Year<-W2004$YEAR
Month<-W2004$MONTH_NAME
Event<-W2004$EVENT_TYPE
Type<-W2004$CZ_TYPE
County<-W2004$CZ_NAME
Direct_Death<-W2004$DEATHS_DIRECT
Indirect_Death<-W2004$DEATHS_INDIRECT
Direct_Injury<-W2004$INJURIES_DIRECT
Indirect_Injury<-W2004$INJURIES_INDIRECT
W2004$DAMAGE_PROPERTY<-as.numeric(W2004$DAMAGE_PROPERTY)
Damage_Property<-W2004$DAMAGE_PROPERTY
l <- cbind( all the columns up there) 
print(l)
```

Comment: You need to at least show us all the abbreviations and what they mean.  Most likely, you can cleanup your data, but you need to show that data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen what do you mean? I have a table of data with different columns so for example in my code w2004 is the name of the data and DAMAGE_PROPERTY is the column in the table. Every data entry in the column is a string that either has a number such as "8.6k" or NA. So I am trying to convert it to 8600 and 0 respectively.

Comment: @mathgirl I attempted an answer below, which works at least for the data you showed, and might be easily extended to anything else you have in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the letter and use `switch()` which is easily maintainable, if you want to add additional symbols it is very easy.

First, the setup:

```
options(scipen = 999) # to prevent R from printing scientific numbers
library(stringr) # to extract letters
```

This is the sample vector:

```
numbers_with_letters <- c("1.00M", "8.6k", 50)
```

Use `lapply()` to loop through vector, extract the letter, replace it with a number, remove the letter, convert to numeric, and multiply:

```
lapply(numbers_with_letters, function(x) {
  letter <- str_extract(x, "[A-Za-z]")

  letter_to_num <- switch(letter, 
                          k = 1000,
                          M  = 1000000,
                          1) # 1 is the default option if no letter found

  numbers_with_letters <- as.numeric(gsub("[A-Za-z]", "", x))

  #remove all NAs and replace with 0
  numbers_with_letters[is.na(numbers_with_letters)] <- 0 

  return(numbers_with_letters * letter_to_num)

})
```

This returns:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1000000

[[2]]
[1] 8600

[[3]]
[1] 50

[[4]]
[1] 0
```

Comment: what if I have NA in the column how to I treat that?

Comment: Would adding a line such as NA = 0 work? Because I want to also replace all the NAs in the data to 0

Answer (score 3):

We can try using a case when expression here, to map each type of unit to a bona fide number.  Going with the two examples you actually showed us:

```
library(dplyr)

x <- c("1.00M", "8.6k")
result <- case_when(
    grepl("\\d+k$", x) ~ as.numeric(sub("\\D+$", "", x)) * 1000,
    grepl("\\d+M$", x) ~ as.numeric(sub("\\D+$", "", x)) * 1000000,
    TRUE ~ as.numeric(sub("\\D+$", "", x))
)
```

Comment: How does it solve it when there is a case of NA as one of the data entry?

Comment: @mathematicsgirl It doesn't do anything for NA values, which would just remain as NA (I think).  But, you never gave any special logic for handling NA values.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm oversimplifying here, but . . .

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(property_damage = c("8.6k", "NA"))

data %>%
 mutate(
  as_number = if_else(
   property_damage != "NA",
   str_extract(property_damage, "\\d+\\.*\\d*"),
   "0"
  ),
  as_number = as.numeric(as_number)
 )
```